# Grabbing multiple variables from a url in php

Tags: php, url, if-statement

I'm new to programming so I write logic the way I think it works for me. It may looks stupid to some of you but im in a learning process. I'm trying to use php `if` and `elseif` conditions to display information based on the url variable. It works fine when I only have one condition however I was wondering how can I make this work with multiple conditions on the same page without getting undefined index errors? Or maybe my logic is flawed?

Here what i'm trying to do:

1. Click on a link to obtain variable
2. Grab variable in the url
3. Use variable to display something specific on the dashboard

[Picture of Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huLGO.png)

**leftsidemenu.php**

```
<a href='home.php?viewcompanystructure=companystructure&company=<?php echo(rand(100000000,100000000000));?>'>Company Structure</a>

   <a href='home.php?setupqualifications=qualificationssetup&company=<?php echo(rand(100000000,100000000000));?>'>
            Qualifications Setup
            </a>

  <a href='home.php?viewprojectsclients=projectsclients&company=<?php echo(rand(100000000,100000000000));?>'>
                Projects/Client Setup</a>
```

**dashboard.php**

```
<?php
$companytable = $_GET['viewcompanystructure'] ;
if($companytable == 'companystructure') :

    include 'tables/companytable.php';
return true;
?>

<?php
$qualificationsetuptable = $_GET['setupqualifications'] ;
elseif($qualificationsetuptable == 'qualificationssetup') :
     include 'tables/qualificationsetuptable.php'
?>

<?php
$projectclientstable = $_GET['viewprojectsclients'] ;
elseif($projectclientstable == 'projectsclients'):
     include 'tables/projectclientstable.php'
?>

<?php else: ?>
Display something else here.

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I believe your `return true;` will cause the PHP to exit and stop processing anything else. It is used for returning a value from a function to the calling method, but as you aren't using a function you can remove it.

Comment: When I dont escape with `return true;` I get undefined index from the `if-statement` that is not getting read.

Comment: I assume because `$qualificationsetuptable = $_GET['setupqualifications'] ;` is actually within the first if-statement, and you're also not testing that your $_GET indexes such as `$_GET['viewcompanystructure']` are set in the first place

Answer (score 0):

If all you're doing is selecting which include to use, I'd like to suggest a alternative to your code layout.

for the given url `home.php?view=companystructure`...

```
switch( ( isset( $_GET['view'] ) === true ) ? $_GET['view'] : null )
{
  case 'companystructure':
    include('tables/companytable.php');
    break;
  case 'setupqualifications'
    include('tables/qualificationsetuptable');
    break;
  case 'viewprojectsclients':
    include('tables/projectclientstable.php');
    break;
  default:
    include('dosomethingelse.php');
    break;
}
```

Comment: I just read about switch statement I haven't thought of it. Its a "prettier" solution but I cant mark you as answer because it does not work in my code nothing happens.

Comment: That's fine, I'd suggest ensuring all aspects of error reporting are enabled, generally it's fairly rare to get a white screen with PHP unless something's going very wrong.